# Explain why the following map is NOT a scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, inner-products

> $\langle,\rangle:V \times V \to \mathbb{R}. V = \{f : [0,1] \to
> > \mathbb {R}\ : f   \text { is continuous}\},$ $$\langle f,g\rangle =f(0)g(0).$$

I know that a scalar product on $V$ is a map $\langle,\rangle:V \times V \to K$ which associates to each pair $(v,w)$ a scalar denoted by $\langle v, w \rangle$, satisfying the following:

- Linearity in the first variable
- Hermitian symmetry(or symmetry in the real case)
- Positivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write down the proof that the mapping satisfies all three properties.

**Hint**:

Focus on the positivity. The mapping satisfies the first two conditions, but it is not positive for all nonzero functions.

---

Just to repeat the property of positivity that needs to hold:

> For all $x\in X$, $\langle x, x\rangle \geq 0$, **and** if $\langle x, x\rangle = 0$, then $x=0$.

Comment: Yes, I know the property , but I can't think of any example of function such that f(0)f(0) is less than zero...

Comment: @Rosalia.d98 You can't. But you can find a function such that $\langle f, f\rangle = 0$ even though $f$ is not the zero element of $V$. (remember again, what is the zero element of $V$?)

Comment: Is it the constant function e(x)=1, for any x in V? So f(0)e(0) = f(0) ?

Comment: @Rosalia.d98 No, the constant function $e(x)=1$ is **not** the zero element of $V$. Remember, the zero element $0\in V$ is such an element for which $v+0=v$ for all $v\in V$.

Comment: Ok, then could it be the constant function e(x)=0? And then I can select a function f, for example f(x)=x and see that f(0)=0 even if f is not e. Is that what you are trying to say? Sorry if I'm tremendously stupid, is the first time I work with scalar products.

Comment: @Rosalia.d98 That's exactly it! $e$ defined as $e(x)=0$ is indeed the zero element of $V$. And the mapping is not a scalar product because you **cannot** conclude that $f=e$ just because $\langle f,f\rangle = 0$. Indeed, the function $f(x)=x$ is a counterexample, and any other function that satisfies the condition $f(0)=0$ is, as well! Well done!

Comment: @Rosalia.d98 You are **far** from stupid, you are confused. This is a new topic, and you have zero intuition with it, so of course you will need to solve it using slow steps. That's how you learn math. But you **did it**, you solved the problem using strict definitions and careful steps, and only a little guidance from me (I only told you where you went wrong, not where to go), so don't for god's sake, feel stupid! Feel free to feel unexperienced, sure, but don't feel stupid!

Answer (score 0):

The last property actually has two parts or at least often is stated that way. First part is $\langle u, u\rangle\ge 0$ which certainly holds, but the second part is $\langle u, u\rangle = 0\Leftrightarrow u=0$ which isn't quite true.

However the last can be achieved by collapsing vectors by using equivalence classes of the relation $\langle u-v, u-v\rangle=0$ which would mean that they are represented by the value of the function at $0$ which basically makes the space $\mathbb R$.